# Spelling/Typo on the /Privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, privileges

&ndash appears within the privileges description page

> All Privileges
>
> When your fellow users vote up your
>   questions and answers on Stack
>   Overflow, you generate reputation.
>   Reputation is a rough measure of:
>
> ```
> How much the community trusts you
> Your communication skills
> The quality and relevancy of your questions and answers
> ```
>
> As you earn reputation from your
>   peers, you earn the community's trust
>   **&ndash** and will be granted additional privileges on Stack
>   Overflow.
>
> The complete list of privileges is
>   listed on the right, in ascending
>   order. The most basic privileges are
>   at the bottom; the most advanced at
>   the top.
>
> Click on any privilege to learn more
>   about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed in dev