# Typo "Aside form" in Privileges - Edit Questions and Answers page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, privileges-page

There is a typo in the first sentence of the last paragraph of the MSO [Edit Questions and Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) privilege description:

> Aside form reviewing suggested edits, the low quality posts queue is
>   also made available.

"Aside form" should be "Aside from".

I reviewed other MSO posts regarding typos in (SO) documentation (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169334/219145), [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66938/219145), and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56604/219145)): posting like this is the way to have someone confirm and fix what I noticed, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. ;P *pretends it wasn't him that made the spelling error*

Comment: I didn't realize we could edit that!

Comment: @Seth: Only on MSO you can. :) I don't remember if there was a reputation requirement or not.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I never saw the option before ;)

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the quick response, @animuson - with a LOL-worthy dose of humor no less. :)  Hey, it was one of those insidious context-based misspellings that spell checkers have a hard time catching: I've made plenty of them!

Comment: @Seth it's considered a tag wiki from editing point of view, but from quick test 1 rep users can't suggest an edit like they can for ordinary tag wiki. Can you see "edit wiki" link in the bottom of [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, I can see it. That's how I noticed it was editable ;) I don't see it on any other sites though.. Must be a meta only thing as Animuson says.

Comment: @Seth so probably it requires just [Edit community wiki questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) (I think that until you have 20K rep it also requires peer review by two 5K+ users). As for Meta only you're right, this site act as the "root" and there's a daily job that update the privilege pages all across the network.

Comment: I saw somewhere that the requirement was just 2,000 reputation (there's certainly no suggested edit system for it). I can't find the post now, though.